# How to handle asynchronous call in redux react application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am beginner of react application. I need handle asynchronous call in my application.

For the implement asynchronous call  is there any library for that ?

How to implement asynchronous call  using library ?

Comment: You need to use thunk middleware for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the implement asynchronous call  you can use following library with react-redux

1. [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)
2. [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise)
3. [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

You can learn asynchronous call handling using library documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla ReactJS and your App does not need any Flux or Redux to control the state of the App, you can use React life-cycle method `componentWillMount` for that with builtin `fetch` method or library like `axios`

If your Application needs `Flux` or `Redux` then I personally recommend `Redux` over `Flux` and you can use `redux-thunk` middleware for that. for example

```
const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';

function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}

function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

For more see http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for how to use async actions : http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

You define it like so when configuring the store:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware
  )
)
```

And you use it in the actions like so:

```
function fetchAction(data) {
  // Return a function, this function will be activated the the thunk middleware with dispatch as parameter
  return function (dispatch) {
    // Dispatch some action before fetch (like setting loading)
    dispatch(requestData(data));

    // return a promise of the fetch
    return fetch('yoururl')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>
        // dispatch a new action when you get your data
        dispatch(receivedData(data,json))
      ).catch (e = > 
        // you can also dispatch an error
        dispatch(errorData(data,e));
      )

  }
}
```